# Is it possible to Highlight all Animation keyframes in the dope sheet and make all frames stick to a specific location, all at once?

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet, timeline, axis

I downloaded two animations from Mixamo and imported it into blender. Both animations are an idle animation and a random action animation. The action animation starts at a completely different location when compared to idle animation that starts right in the middle location of x,y, and z.

This action animation has over 40 key frames and was wondering if its possible for me to highlight all keyframes of the animation and change all frames of the animation to be in the same location at once. This is so I don't have to change the location of every frame individually. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: If they didn't use the root bone in the animation, you could delete the keyframe for the root bone's location on both actions/animations, then move them where they need to go.  Won't work well if they used the root bone as part of the animation though, so make a copy file first.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do as @Policesate suggests, make a backup of the original Blend file, then - Try making a master parent for the model.  From there the included animations should become local to the parent.  Either enter in your desired location for the parent or simply drag it there - keyframe that.

The included animations should stay with it.  If they've keyframed the root bone, and it takes the model somewhere else for the idle state or other action, go into the Graph editor and drag all of that action's X/Y keyframes up or down to drag it back.  Press G Y to ensure you don't drift sideways in the editor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm going to try this.

Comment: Any problems, just ask...